# Massive merge commit in Git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge, git-rebase

I know that **rebasing** works by transferring each local commit to the updated master branch one at a time, but is there a way to see all of the merge conflicts at one time after a massive merge commit, rather than one at a time? Thanks!

Comment: define "see", you mean see actual conflicts or just listing the conflicting files like "git status"?

Comment: Hey Fredrik, I want to see all of the actual conflicts, just not one at a time. Example, like pouring out a whole bag of M&M's and seeing all of the blue ones at a single glance, rather than picking the blue ones out of the bag one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

During a rebase, you can see conflicts, and this can happen at multiple times at different stages of the rebase.

If you want to see the conflicts only once, you could squash the history that is being rebased into a single commit and rebase that single commit instead. Save the merge conflicts into a file. Then reset back to where you were, and do a rebase which preserves the individual history.

Say we want to rebase `master` onto the upstream `origin/master`. They are diverged so there will be conflicts. First, let us interactively rebase all the `master` commits which are not in the upstream back onto `master`, and squash them:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git tag starting-point
$ git rebase --interactive $(git merge-base master origin/master)
# in the edit window, "pick" the first commit, "squash" all the rest!
```

Now there is only a single new commit on `master` with the merge base as its parent. Merge or rebase it:

```
$ git rebase
```

Now all the conflicts occur together, due to everything being in one commit, so now you can view them all with one diff:

```
$ git diff
```

This is in a special "diff of a diff" format. To see an ordinary diff:

```
$ git diff HEAD
```

Save these conflicts to a file:

```
$ git diff HEAD > conflicts.diff
```

Now, escape back to the starting point, putting `master` into the state which it had:

```
$ git rebase abort
$ git reset --hard starting-point
```

Now you have the `conflicts.diff`; you can now merge or rebase conventionally, making whatever use of that information you have in mind.

They may not be exactly the same conflicts that you encounter when rebasing the individual 
commits.